# How to fit data with error bars with smooth curve?

Tags: plotting

```
   ErrorListPlot[{{{0.05/0.17, 0.08/0.17}, 
   ErrorBar[0.01/0.17]}, {{0.05/0.18, 0.08/0.18}, 
   ErrorBar[0.01/0.18]}, {{0.05/0.19, 0.07/0.19}, 
   ErrorBar[0.01/0.19]}, {{0.05/0.2, 0.07/0.2}, 
   ErrorBar[0.01/0.2]}, {{0.05/0.21, 0.07/0.21}, 
   ErrorBar[0.01/0.21]}, {{0.05/0.22, 0.07/0.22}, 
   ErrorBar[0.01/0.22]}, {{0.05/0.23, 0.07/0.23}, 
   ErrorBar[0.01/0.23]}, {{0.05/0.24, 0.07/0.24}, 
   ErrorBar[0.01/0.24]}, {{0.05/0.25, 0.06/0.25}, 
   ErrorBar[0.01/0.25]}, {{0.05/0.26, 0.06/0.26}, 
   ErrorBar[0.01/0.26]}, {{0.05/0.27, 0.06/0.27}, 
   ErrorBar[0.01/0.27]}, {{0.05/0.28, 0.06/0.28}, 
   ErrorBar[0.01/0.28]}, {{0.05/0.29, 0.05/0.29}, 
   ErrorBar[0.01/0.29]}, {{0.05/0.3, 0.05/0.3}, 
   ErrorBar[0.01/0.3]}, {{0.05/0.31, 0.05/0.31}, 
   ErrorBar[0.01/0.31]}, {{0.05/0.32, 0.04/0.32}, 
   ErrorBar[0.01/0.32]}, {{0.05/0.33, 0.04/0.33}, 
   ErrorBar[0.01/0.33]}, {{0.05/0.34, 0.03/0.34}, 
   ErrorBar[0.01/0.34]}, {{0.05/0.35, 0.03/0.35}, 
   ErrorBar[0.01/0.35]}, {{0.05/0.36, 0.02/0.36}, 
   ErrorBar[0.01/0.36]}, {{0.05/0.37, 0.02/0.37}, 
   ErrorBar[0.01/0.37]}, {{0.05/0.16, 0.08/0.16}, 
   ErrorBar[0.01/0.16]}, {{0.05/0.15, 0.08/0.15}, 
   ErrorBar[0.01/0.15]}, {{0.05/0.14, 0.08/0.14}, 
   ErrorBar[0.01/0.14]}, {{0.05/0.13, 0.09/0.13}, 
   ErrorBar[0.01/0.13]}, {{0.05/0.135, 0.08/0.135}, 
   ErrorBar[0.01/0.135]}, {{0.05/0.145, 0.08/0.145}, 
   ErrorBar[0.01/0.145]}, {{0.05/0.155, 0.08/0.155}, 
   ErrorBar[0.01/0.155]}, {{0.05/0.165, 0.08/0.165}, 
   ErrorBar[0.01/0.165]}, {{0.05/0.175, 0.08/0.175}, 
   ErrorBar[0.01/0.175]}, {{0.05/0.185, 0.08/0.185}, 
   ErrorBar[0.01/0.185]}, {{0.05/0.195, 0.07/0.195}, 
   ErrorBar[0.01/0.195]}, {{0.05/0.205, 0.07/0.205}, 
   ErrorBar[0.01/0.205]}, {{0.05/0.215, 0.07/0.215}, 
   ErrorBar[0.01/0.215]}, {{0.05/0.375, 0.00/0.375}, 
   ErrorBar[0.01/0.375]}}]
```

[image: Plot of above data]

I have above data with error bars, and I try to connect those dots to make a smooth line. I have no idea what fit model should I use and the fitting doesn't have to be linear and can be wavy. The fitting is something looks like this:
[image]

How can I do this? Thx!

Comment: What might be causing the "jumps" in the data?  The data is pretty linear for a few points in a row and then there's a jump.  And the jumps take longer to occur with increasing values of the horizontal variable.

Comment: I am guessing the "jumps" in the data is due to the limiting digit of the data, for example, those 0.08 in the data can be 0.081, 0.082 etc, but it is really hard to get the data to the accuracy of 0.001, and that is why I am including the error bar.

Comment: The size of the error bars between the horizontal values of .275 to 0.375 are much too large for the errors about the line to be independent.  There must be some serial correlation.  Are these successive measurements on a single experimental unit?  I ask because besides the "shape" of the curve, approximating the error structure is important, too.

Comment: Well, these error bars are large because if you look at my above data, .275 to .375 correspond to 0.05/0.18 to 0.05/0.13. Their corresponding error bar magnitude is 0.01/0.18 to 0.01/0.13 (where the 0.01 is fixed). Since 0.13 to 0.18 are small numbers, the error bars should be large.

Comment: We speak a different language and I'm not communicating well.  It is obvious to you that the "error bar magnitude" becomes larger with increasing horizontal values.  Is that one standard deviation from some probability distribution which increases linearly with larger horizontal values?  A plot of the "error bar magnitudes" vs. the horizontal variable is near perfectly linear.

Comment: Sorry, I did not make myself clear about those data. In the data, I have 0.05/b for x-axis, c/b for y-axis. The error bar is 0.01/b. The 0.01 error is for the number c.

Comment: Are these values from the area Atomic-force microscopy? If yes, raw data  make more sense.

Answer (score 2):

Copy and paste the list inside the `ErrorListPlot`

Then you can extract the `x` and `y` points of the list via:

```
data = {
  {{0.05/0.17, 0.08/0.17}, ErrorBar[0.01/0.17]},
  {{0.05/0.18, 0.08/0.18}, ErrorBar[0.01/0.18]},
  {{0.05/0.19, 0.07/0.19}, ErrorBar[0.01/0.19]},
   .
   .
   .
{{0.05/0.375, 0.00/0.375}, ErrorBar[0.01/0.375]}
  }[[All, 1]]
```

A reasonable fit to the data is a third degree polynomial

```
sol = FindFit[data, a + b x + c x^2 + d x^3,
         {{a, -1}, {b, 10}, {c, -30}, {d, 35}}, x]

(* {a -> -0.878902, b -> 10.1701, c -> -29.4332, d -> 34.9043} *)
```

Check the fit

```
Show[
 ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> Black],
 Plot[a + b x + c x^2 + d x^3 /. sol,
  {x, 0.1, 0.4},
   PlotStyle -> Red
  ],
 PlotRange -> {{0.1, 0.4}, {0, 0.8}},
 AxesOrigin -> {0.1, 0}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 1):

Just to illustrate 'getting under the hood' of graphics and to illustrate some other features:

Setup:

```
Needs["ErrorBarPlots`"]
eblp = {{{0.05/0.17, 0.08/0.17}, 
    ErrorBar[0.01/0.17]}, {{0.05/0.18, 0.08/0.18}, 
    ErrorBar[0.01/0.18]}, {{0.05/0.19, 0.07/0.19}, 
    ErrorBar[0.01/0.19]}, {{0.05/0.2, 0.07/0.2}, 
    ErrorBar[0.01/0.2]}, {{0.05/0.21, 0.07/0.21}, 
    ErrorBar[0.01/0.21]}, {{0.05/0.22, 0.07/0.22}, 
    ErrorBar[0.01/0.22]}, {{0.05/0.23, 0.07/0.23}, 
    ErrorBar[0.01/0.23]}, {{0.05/0.24, 0.07/0.24}, 
    ErrorBar[0.01/0.24]}, {{0.05/0.25, 0.06/0.25}, 
    ErrorBar[0.01/0.25]}, {{0.05/0.26, 0.06/0.26}, 
    ErrorBar[0.01/0.26]}, {{0.05/0.27, 0.06/0.27}, 
    ErrorBar[0.01/0.27]}, {{0.05/0.28, 0.06/0.28}, 
    ErrorBar[0.01/0.28]}, {{0.05/0.29, 0.05/0.29}, 
    ErrorBar[0.01/0.29]}, {{0.05/0.3, 0.05/0.3}, 
    ErrorBar[0.01/0.3]}, {{0.05/0.31, 0.05/0.31}, 
    ErrorBar[0.01/0.31]}, {{0.05/0.32, 0.04/0.32}, 
    ErrorBar[0.01/0.32]}, {{0.05/0.33, 0.04/0.33}, 
    ErrorBar[0.01/0.33]}, {{0.05/0.34, 0.03/0.34}, 
    ErrorBar[0.01/0.34]}, {{0.05/0.35, 0.03/0.35}, 
    ErrorBar[0.01/0.35]}, {{0.05/0.36, 0.02/0.36}, 
    ErrorBar[0.01/0.36]}, {{0.05/0.37, 0.02/0.37}, 
    ErrorBar[0.01/0.37]}, {{0.05/0.16, 0.08/0.16}, 
    ErrorBar[0.01/0.16]}, {{0.05/0.15, 0.08/0.15}, 
    ErrorBar[0.01/0.15]}, {{0.05/0.14, 0.08/0.14}, 
    ErrorBar[0.01/0.14]}, {{0.05/0.13, 0.09/0.13}, 
    ErrorBar[0.01/0.13]}, {{0.05/0.135, 0.08/0.135}, 
    ErrorBar[0.01/0.135]}, {{0.05/0.145, 0.08/0.145}, 
    ErrorBar[0.01/0.145]}, {{0.05/0.155, 0.08/0.155}, 
    ErrorBar[0.01/0.155]}, {{0.05/0.165, 0.08/0.165}, 
    ErrorBar[0.01/0.165]}, {{0.05/0.175, 0.08/0.175}, 
    ErrorBar[0.01/0.175]}, {{0.05/0.185, 0.08/0.185}, 
    ErrorBar[0.01/0.185]}, {{0.05/0.195, 0.07/0.195}, 
    ErrorBar[0.01/0.195]}, {{0.05/0.205, 0.07/0.205}, 
    ErrorBar[0.01/0.205]}, {{0.05/0.215, 0.07/0.215}, 
    ErrorBar[0.01/0.215]}, {{0.05/0.375, 0.00/0.375}, 
    ErrorBar[0.01/0.375]}};
```

Producing plot with error bars, fitted curve (`LinearModelFit` but could also do as per Jack LaVigne or whatever model relevant to data) and producing legend.

```
da = Normal@LinearModelFit[eblp[[All, 1]], {1, x, x^2, x^3}, x];
Framed@Legended[
  Show[ErrorListPlot[eblp] /. 
      Point[x__] :> {Red, PointSize[0.02], Point[x]}, 
     Plot[da, {x, ##}, PlotStyle -> {Black, Dashed}]] & @@ 
   MinMax[eblp[[All, 1, 1]]], 
  Placed[Column[{PointLegend[{Red}, {"data"}], 
     LineLegend[{Directive[Black, Dashed]}, {da}]}], Below]]
```

[image]